# Stop changes effect one specific folder in GIT

Tags: git, gitignore

I am developing a PhP application and using git to deploy it on heroku I am new to git

the project is almost about to terminate now my log folder shouldn't affect the server anymore I mean from now the log files should only saves the server status not my local branch, The structure is like this:

```
 MyProject
 |
  -logfolder/*
```

I put logfolder/* 
in the gitignore file but still the changes in my own logfolder are pushing alongside with other changes to server,..

what shall I do about it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to get this ADDED files out of the index by:

```
git rm -r --cached logfolder
git add logfolder
git commit -m "fixing .gitignore"
```

Comment: It didn't work it removed the folder and it files from the server copy as well it doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Then back to the commit before this false advice. Sorry. But you have still to get them out of the index.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove logfolder files from gits index and add a `.gitignore` file in `logfile` directory, The file contains the following.

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

This link shows how to make empty directory. [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

And these command should fix your problem.

```
git rm --cached -r logfile
git add logfile/.gitignore
```

Then try to see everything is ok with, git status. And commit your changes.

You don't need to mention "logfile/*" in `.gitignore` root file.

Comment: I think You didn't get my question clearly, I don't need to make a folder empty my question is this: I have log folder that contains log files I uploaded the whole project on the server but I don't need the my local log files effect the server copy anymore, obviously because they are supposed to log the server. The git rm --cached -r logfolder will remove the directory in server as well

Comment: `git rm --chached -r logfolder` will not delete any file or folder it just removes them from git.

Comment: No you're right it doesn't delete anything from local copy but as soon as the next push to the server is committed the folder will be deleted from server copy